# Get the mac address of devices connected to same wifi in android

Tags: android, wifi

I know this question has been asked several times but there isn't a proper code snippet or answer in SO.

I am developing an android app which gives the list of MAC addresses (IP address or device name anything ,etc. ) of all the Devices connected to a wifi network (the network in which the mobile containing this app is installed).

Is there any API's in android to achieve this or else how can we do this.

**Note : Please provide the answer with a code snippet**

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible to get Mac Address of other devices. However you can get IP addresses.

Comment: You can use Nmap. Nmap is now ported on android. Will try to give code snippet later as I am not on my machine.

Comment: Okie thanks waiting for the code. Meanwhile let me look about Nmap.